# Extract part of a text file with python

Tags: python, list, extract

I have a text file which is of the form :

*Initialization 
  Background
 Starting_Measurement1 
 1 
 2 
3 
 ...

 100 
 End_Measurement1
Starting_Measurement2 
 1 
 2 
3 
 ...

 75 
 End_Measurement2*

I would like to store the values between *Starting_Measurement1* and *End_Measurement1* and then between *Starting_Measurement2* and *End_Measurement2*, but the number of value is variable

Is there a clean way to do this in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `re`:

```
import re

re_numbers = re.compile(
    r"Starting_Measurement(1|2)(.*?)End_Measurement\1", re.DOTALL
)

with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    res = {
        n: numbers.strip().splitlines()
        for n, numbers in re_numbers.findall(file.read())
    }
```

Result `res` for the following file `file.txt`

```
Initialization
Background
Starting_Measurement1
1
2
End_Measurement1
Starting_Measurement2
1
2
3
4
5
End_Measurement2
End
```

is

```
{'1': ['1', '2'], '2': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']}
```

See [regex101-demo](https://regex101.com/r/TxPrQd/1).

Answer (score 0):

```
b = textInput.split('\n')

start1 = b.index('Starting_Measurement1')
end1 = b.index('End_Measurement1')

measureList1 = list(b[start1:end1])
```

And repeat for the other Measurements

Answer (score 0):

It's perhaps not the most elegant solution, but it should do what you want:

Contents of text file named `data.txt`:

```
Initialization
Background
Starting_Measurement1
1
2
3
4
5
100
End_Measurement1
Starting_Measurement2
1
2
3
75
End_Measurement2
```

Code that reads the file and extracts the numbers into a list of lists:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    s = f.read()

all_measurements = []
reading = False
for line in s.splitlines():
    if line.startswith('Starting_Measurement'):
        current_measurements = []
        reading = True
    elif line.startswith('End_Measurement'):
        all_measurements.append(current_measurements)
        reading = False
    elif reading:
        value = int(line)
        current_measurements.append(value)

print(all_measurements)
```

Resulting in:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 100], [1, 2, 3, 75]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = "measurements.txt"

measurements = []
measurement_lines = []
line_in_measurement = False
with open(filename, "rt") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip("\n")
        if "Starting_Measurement" in line:
            measurement_lines = []
            line_in_measurement = True
        elif "End_Measurement" in line:
            measurements.append(measurement_lines)
            line_in_measurement = False
        elif line_in_measurement:
            measurement_lines.append(line)

for measure_number, measure in enumerate(measurements):
    print(f"measurement {measure_number}")
    print(measure)
```